How to have a Facebook App which can create more than 25 ad accounts?
I'm developing a SaaS where users can select from a variety of templates and publish their Facebook ads. I'd like to have a separate Ad Account for each user so if there is a problem with one ad account this will not negatively affect all software users.
In my business manager it shows me that my ad account limit is 22. We are expecting close to a hundred users after releasing the platform.
Question
Will the limit increase once the app has been verified by Facebook? Or is there a workaround? I've also been thinking about creating a Business Manager + Ad Account per user but I'm not sure if this will result in loss of control or which consequences this may have. I have already contacted the Facebook support but they have not been helpful.
Any ideas?
